# in_category('category-sluga') returns true for Archive page of Category 'category-slugb'

Tags: categories, widgets

I've got a Category Archive page with name `category-slugb.php`.

I have a sidebar with some Widget Logic that uses `in_category('category-sluga')`.

What's odd is that on this Category Archive page (i.e. for all Posts of `category-slugb.php`) the `in_category('category-sluga')` condition is being triggered as `true`.

Why? Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Basically, I do not want the sidebar that has the `in_category('category-sluga')` Widget Logic to appear on the `category-slugb.php` Category Archive Page.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

review https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category vs https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category

to check for a category archive, use https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category

Answer (score 0):

`in_category()` is the incorrect function to use. This function checks that the current post object (which equates to the first post in the loop on an archive) is in the given category.

The function you need is `is_category()` which checks that the current query is for the archive of the given category.